# How to append the filename to every

Tags: awk

I have 32 cells in a file so i need to read the name of the file and append the file name at the starting of every line how can i do it

example

```
MACRO XYZ 
PIN AB 
DIRECTION INPUT ;
PIN BC
DIRECTION INPUT ;

MACRO  GEN 
PIN DECSEL_STG2[0]
DIRECTION INPUT ;
PIN DECSEL_STG1[0]
DIRECTION INPUT ;
```

what i need as a output

```
MACRO XYZ 
XYZ PIN AB 
XYZ DIRECTION INPUT ; 
XYZ PIN BC
XYZ DIRECTION INPUT ;


MACRO GEN 
GEN PIN DECSEL_STG2[0]
GEN DIRECTION INPUT ; 
GEN PIN DECSEL_STG1[0]
GEN DIRECTION INPUT ;
```

Comment: akshay siddamal:: please use code tags for your sample(s) input/output in your posts.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a relatively simple `awk` script, as per the following transcript:

```
pax$ printf "MACRO XYZ\nline 2\nline3\n\nMACRO GEN\nline 6\n\n\n" | awk '
...$    $1=="MACRO"{mac=$2;print;next}$NF>0{print mac" "$0;next}{print}'
MACRO XYZ
XYZ line 2
XYZ line3
.
MACRO GEN
GEN line 6
.
.
```

(those `.` characters are added by me just to show where the blank lines are).

Expanding on the script:

```
$1 == "MACRO" {      # If first word is macro:
    mac=$2;          #    store second word,
    print;           #    print line,
    next             #    and go get next line.
}
$NF > 0 {            # Otherwise, if line has some fields:
    print mac" "$0;  #    print stored macro name before line,
    next             #    and go get next line.
}
{                    # Otherwise (lines with no fields):
    print            #    just print it as is.
}
```